# Applications which consume and analyze all personal data for quantified self purposes (and health insights)

Tags: monitoring, data-analysis, health

I’m wondering if there’s any go to app which can automatically process as much available data as possible about me, ie generated by my phone and or smartwatch, and just use machine learning to try to provide any insights.

I tend to use Apple devices but am open to others.

The motivation was for me to try to figure out what I can do to reduce fatigue I sometimes get. It would be cool to see over time what factors seem to play a role in causing or alleviating fatigue.

It would be much better if devices could nonstop digest all available data rather than me having to choose specific factors to log.